# Combine data from different tables in a View. What is wrong with my Code?

Tags: sql-server-2008, view

I want to create a view that will present details of the vehicle and the amount of loans.
I have a problem with the placing in this view [vehicle_brand],[vehicle_type],[Color] that come from another table. I do not know how to combine data from different tables ... I'll be very grateful for your help.

My tables and my unfinished code view:

```
[dbo].[Loan](
[id_Loan] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[registration_number] FOREIGN KEY [char](10) NULL,
[Loan_time] [datetime] NOT NULL, ...

[dbo].[vehicle](
[registration_number] [char](10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[id_vehicle_brand] FOREIGN KEY [int] NULL,
[id_TypuPojazdu] FOREIGN KEY [int] NULL,
[id_vehicle_color] FOREIGN KEY [int] NULL,


[dbo].[Color](
[id_vehicle_color] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[Color] [char](20) NOT NULL,


[dbo].[vehicle_type](KEY 
[id_vehicle_type] [int] IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[vehicle_type] [char](20) NOT NULL


[dbo].[vehicle_brand](
[id_vehicle_brand] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 [vehicle_brand] [char](50) NOT NULL
```

---

```
 CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_loan_statistics ]
 AS
 with t1 ([registration_number],amount_of_loans)
 as
 (
 select [registration_number], count(*) amount_of_loans
 from [dbo].[Loan]
 group by [registration_number]
 )
 select top 100 percent t1.[registration_number],***[vehicle_brand],  
 [vehicle_type],[Color]***,t1.amount_of_loans
 from t1
 inner join [dbo].[vehicle] p
 on t1.[registration_number]=p.[registration_number]
 order by t1.[registration_number]

 GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [dbo].[Loan].RegistrationNumber is nullable and p.[registration_number] is not, it raises an error.
you can add `where RegistrationNumber is not null`

Comment: Ou, thanks for that. I corrected it. but my main problem is the compatibility of data from different tables - ***[vehicle_brand],  
 [vehicle_type],[Color]*** I dont konowhow to do this...:/

Comment: what do you mean from compatibility?

Comment: hmmm... I used is not the right word. As I mentioned in the top description - I have a problem with the placing in this view [vehicle_brand],[vehicle_type],[Color] becouse this colums are from another tables then Loan. In short, i need a view that will show the following columns [registration_number],[vehicle_brand],  
 [vehicle_type],[Color],amount_of_loans.

Comment: CREATE VIEW ViewName
AS
SELECT [registration_number],[vehicle_brand], [vehicle_type],[Color]
FROM registration inner join vehicle on ....

Comment: I'm really a beginner in sql and I have no idea how I can successfully add your advice to my code. Maybe again, I want to get a view that will calculate amount of loan (in "amount_of_loans" column) and informations about the vehicules ([registration_number],[vehicle_brand], [vehicle_type],[Color]) that come from other tables.

Comment: @SuA : what is your primary/ foreign key relation in your tables?(Do u know anything about them)